# What does the Lattice actually means in the Small World Propensity formula?

Tags: graph-theory, applications, python, network

I am studying small-world networks and I came across the formula of **Small World Propensity** (reference: https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0216146.s001). And I am having trouble understanding the Lattice in the formula. Please find the detailed problem after the definition.

**Definition:** The small-world propensity measures the extent to which a network is characterized by high levels of local clustering and low average path length. It is defined as follows:

$\Phi = 1-\sqrt{\frac{{\Delta_T}^2+{\Delta_L}^2}{2}}$

where

$\Delta_T = \frac{T_{lattice}-T_{observed}}{T_{lattice}-T_{random}}$

and

$\Delta_L = \frac{L_{observed}-L_{random}}{L_{lattice}-L_{random}}$

with

$L$ being the path length of a network, i.e. the average shortest path length between all node pairs, and $T$ representing the network clustering (transitivity) coefficient, defined as the average of node-specific clustering coefficient values.

**Problem:** I am trying to code this using the [`python-igraph` library](https://igraph.org/python) and my understanding is that the we have to calculate $T$ and $L$ values using -

1. random graph for $T_{random}$ and $L_{random}$
2. k-regular graph for $T_{lattice}$ and $L_{lattice}$

but when I checked the documentation of `igraph` I noticed that apart from `K_Regular(n, k)` function [(ref. page no. 123  in the pdf)](https://igraph.org/python/doc/python-igraph.pdf) there is a separate function called `Lattice(dim)` [(ref. page no. 124 in the pdf)](https://igraph.org/python/doc/python-igraph.pdf) that generates a regular lattice. Screenshots attached below, in case this pdf is removed in the future.

[image: K_Regular]
[image: Lattice]

Now, I am confused that should I use `K_Regular(n, k)` or `Lattice(dim)` to calculate $T_{lattice}$ and $L_{lattice}$? And what is the difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, my understanding of creating the regular graphs was wrong in the case of Small World Propensity.

I did a discussion with people working in the field of brain connectivity and with the help of [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep22057) (in this Small World Propensity is originally discussed), I was able to figure out the meaning of lattice used in this context.

Below I am quoting a few points from the paper that helped me figure it out.

In section **Generating Weighted Small-World Networks**

> 1. Begin with a network of N nodes that are arranged on a lattice and connected to all neighbors within a radius, r.

**In Figure 3a** shows that the initial lattice is a circular graph in which every node is connected to `n` neighbours both on left and right.

> [image: initial lattice]

Now, this confirmed that I needed to use `Lattice(dim)` for generating the initial lattice, but now a second question arose  - **what should be the value of `dim`?**

This was answered in [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/2/3/1683), Figure 2a has explained that such a lattice is **A periodic one-dimensional ( D = 1 ) lattice (i.e. a ring) where each vertex is connected to its n neighbours on left and right.**

> [image: 1 dimensional lattice]

and the documentation of `igraph` for `Lattice` confirmed that I need to put a list containing 1 element (1 dimension), and the value of that element should be the number of nodes to be generated, further, I need to put the number of neighbours on either side to directly connect.

So, If I need 20 nodes and connect 3 neighbours in each direction (so total of 6 neighbours will be connected), function should be:

```
G = ig.Graph().Lattice(dim=[20],nei=3)
```

This generates the following graph.
[image: generated lattice]